# Blog DB question about tags

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I am starting to make a blog in ASP.NET MVC3 using LINQ2SQL and I am wondering what is the best approach on making tags for posts.

Scenario 1:
I simply add another row to `blogPosts` table named `tags`, seperate every tag with commas and when I search for every post containing some tag I just select * where in tags it contains the text I'm after.

Scenario 2:
I add another table called `PostTags` and another called `Tags`. `PostTags` will contain `postID` and `tagID`. `Tags` will contain `ID` and `Tag` itself. Also put up DB relations between these tables.

So which is the best solution?

Comment: In scenario one, I believe that you mean "add another **column**" and not row, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scenario 2 looks better to me as it clearly separates tags in another table making the database more normalized and allowing easier querying by tags. In addition to this you will be able to more easily perform queries on those tags and show them independently of blog posts.

Comment: + you can have database index on tagID and postID which makes queries very fast.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Scenario 1 should be an option at all, it's clearly not good database design, introduce redundant data and will be inefficient to query when you have a lot of rows in your table.